# mongoose aggregate time diffrence

Tags: node.js, mongodb, mongoose, aggregate

my collections look this

```
{
   "_id": { "$oid": "61e7ed06dd937668b3afa22f" },
   "time_duration": {
      "count": 2,
      "timeArr": [
         {
            "_id": { "$oid": "61e7edcfdd937668b3afa238" },
            "start_time": { "$date": "2022-01-18T07:50:34.000Z" },
            "end_time": { "$date": "2022-01-18T09:50:34.000Z" }
         },
         {
            "_id": { "$oid": "61e7ee1faa77f37ceffcec4d" },
            "start_time": { "$date": "2022-01-18T07:50:34.000Z" },
            "end_time": { "$date": "2022-01-18T09:50:34.000Z" }
         },
         {
            "_id": { "$oid": "61e7ee39aa77f37ceffcec5a" },
            "start_time": { "$date": "2022-01-18T07:50:34.000Z" },
            "end_time": { "$date": "2022-01-18T09:50:34.000Z" }
         }
      ]
   },
   "parent_user_id": { "$oid": "61e6643548a14c31cee78ce6" },
   "project_id": { "$oid": "61e67053174f50418f9a71b5" },
   "name_activity": "",
   "timer_status": "stopped",
   "client_id": { "$oid": "6192363c027390b0e4d5b15c" },
   "createdAt": { "$date": "2022-01-19T10:50:46.985Z" },
   "updatedAt": { "$date": "2022-01-19T10:55:53.832Z" },
   "__v": 0
}
```

i want to calculate time diffrence between start_time and end_time

i have tried this code so far

```
let ar = await ActivityRecord.aggregate([
  {
    $project: {
      duration: {
        $divide: [{ $subtract: ["$end_time", "$start_time"] }, 3600000],
      },
    },
  },
]);
```

Comment: Please don't paste screenshots. Use formatted text, see https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/285551

Comment: `end_time` is `1970-01-01 00:00:00`, i.e. 0 - most likely that are wrong data.

Comment: i have update the question and removed the image and it is dummmy data to paste here if you whish i can update another data here

Comment: `start_time` and `end_time` are in an array. Which one you like to get? Please provide expected output sample.

Comment: i just wanted to time_diff between those start_time and end_time

Comment: Once again, please provide a sample of expected output.